# Can Abstract class be used that way or Should I use Interface?

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

I'm sure this question seems simple but I still want to ask. I was reading about abstract classes and found this real time example:

Let's suppose we are defining an iPhone class for Apple and then inheriting it to iPhone5 and iPhone5s sub-classes. Practically we don't want an object of iPhone class since we first need to know the type of iPhone. So the iPhone class should be an abstract class that contains some common behavior to all subclasses like Call(), SMS(). However, we can also add some abstract methods like Model() and Color() into the iPhone class that must be implemented in all the sub-classes depending upon the phone. Whenever we implement the iPhone class into sub classes, say iPhone5s, we don't need to write Call and SMS methods again for the class, we just need to implement the abstract methods.

But my friend told me that such example could be better using interface instead of abstract class. So my question is should I create an interface of iPhone class instead of abstract class, or this approach is good? Please help!

Comment: Did your friend tell you why he thinks an interface would be better, or did he just postulate that it is better?

Comment: @dcastro He told me it is better to keep your methods abstract. However, I think this approach works good Whenever we implement the iPhone class into subclasses, say iPhone5s, we don't need to write Call and SMS methods again for the class. It helps to avoid code duplication. What you think?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces and abstract classes serve different purposes. An interface is used to exclusively declare what the interface to a class must look like in order to qualify as an *X*. You'd use this to define what *a phone* must provide, e.g. a `call(number)` and `sms(number, message)` method.

An abstract class is an *implementation* "with blanks". An abstract class could implement an interface itself. You'd use an abstract `iPhone` class to implement your `Phone` interface; you add code which is common for all iPhones to that abstract class, and leave abstract methods which each *particular* iPhone model must implement itself.

```
interface Phone {

    public function call(number);
    public function sms(number, message);

}

abstract class iPhone implements Phone {

    public function call(number) {
        cellProvider = this.getCellProvider();
        cellProvider.makeCall(number);
        cellProvider.endCall();
    }

    /**
     * Every iPhone model will have different hardware,
     * must return instance of CellProviderInterface here.
     */
    abstract protected function getCellProvider();

    ...

}

class iPhone5S extends iPhone {

    protected function getCellProvider() {
        return this.qualcom12345Chip;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Nice example Man. Just one question why did you create the "Phone interface". We can write the same logic inside the abstract class as well and still follow the hierarchy?

Comment: Sure, I'm just highlighting the different use cases. An interface allows you to implement completely different kinds of things which have nothing in common except for the methods declared in the interface; while a class hierarchy enforces a stricter, well, hierarchy. You could implement a, say, *car* which `implements Phone` if you wanted to; you obviously wouldn't want that in your iPhone class hierarchy.